# Query django model to retrieve set lists

Tags: django, django-models

I want to get all objects associated with a user and split the retrieved list into three different lists in the UI according to some additional logic. I'm currently doing this by setting a `@property` on the model and then in doing a bunch of loops and if/else in the template. This is obviously sub optimal, because I'd like to not include the section headers if there is nothing in the actual section, but since I'm pulling in one large list, there's no `empty` state.

Current:

model

```
class Entry(models.Model):
     user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     publish_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
     favorite = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

view

```
entries = Entry.objects.filter(user=request.user)
```

template

```
<strong>FAVORITES</strong>
{% for obj in entries %}
  {% if obj.group == 'favorites' %}
    ...
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}

<strong>PUBLISHED</strong>
{% for obj in entries %}
  {% if obj.group == 'published' %}
    ...
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}

<strong>DRAFT</strong>
{% for obj in entries %}
  {% if obj.group == 'draft' %}
    ...
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

How should I add a method on the model (e.g. `get_groupings`) that could return a dict with three separate querysets in it ('entries['favorites]=') in a database efficient way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you write to your database seldom and read often, it might be best to save your property in a database field and do a second `.filter()` on this.

Otherwise, yes, you should add a method on the model - that's where this logic belongs. If you want it to return all three of the groups every time, then there is no such thing as more or less database-efficient: just pull all the objects from the db once, as you do now, then use a list comprehension or the like. The performance of this should be no concern. If it is: see first paragraph.